# Can't convert string to integer using Entry boxes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new to tkinter and python in general and i'm having an issue that i can't solve.
In my program i want to take input from the user and transform it into an integer to use that variable later on. The main issue is that i get the error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. I tried different methods by searching online but none of them did work. Any help is well appreciated. Thank you!
[error message on visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir2ih.png)

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()

window.title("Controlla quote")
window.geometry('400x150')

#binari
binari_num=0
def binari(number):
    if number==1:
        binari_num=1
        print("binari= ",binari_num)
    elif number==2:
        binari_num=2
        print("binari= ",binari_num)
    else:
        pass
    return binari_num
#radiobuttons
info = IntVar()
binari_1 = Radiobutton(window, text="1", command=lambda:binari(info.get()),variable=info,value=1).grid(column=1, row=0)
binari_2 = Radiobutton(window, text="2", command=lambda:binari(info.get()),variable=info,value=2).grid(column=2, row=0)
#binari label
binari_scritta=Label(window, text="Binari:").grid(column=0, row=0, stick=W)

#stazionamenti
stazionamenti_label=Label(window, text="Stazionamenti: ").grid(column=0, row=1, stick=W)
stazionamenti_entry=Entry(window)
stazionamenti_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, stick=W)
#conversion stazionamenti
stazionamenti_str= stazionamenti_entry.get()
stazionamenti_num= int(stazionamenti_str)


#avanti
def avanti():
    pass
avanti_btn=Button(window, text="Avanti", command=avanti()).grid(columnspan=50, stick=E)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should remove the two lines: `stazionamenti_str= stazionamenti_entry.get()` and `stazionamenti_num= int(stazionamenti_str)`.  It is pointless to call them right after creating the `Entry` because you would get empty string as the error said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code gets executed right away and when `stazionamenti_entry.get()` is called, its basically an empty string `""`. `int()` requires a valid string which contains only numbers and a minus sign at first place optionally. Strings with spaces or empty string or with non numerical characters give this error.

The error means "the string provided is not convertable to int".

What you can do is make a function and call it when `stazionamenti_entry.get()` is needed and make sure there is numeral data in `stazionamenti_entry`. More precisely you should do it in you `avanti` function.

You can add in some checks before `stazionamenti_num= int(stazionamenti_str)` like:

```py
if stazionamenti_str :
    stazionamenti_num= int(stazionamenti_str)
```

This will make sure that string is not empty.

On OPs request:

```py
.
.
.
stazionamenti_label=Label(window, text="Stazionamenti: ").grid(column=0, row=1, stick=W)
stazionamenti_entry=Entry(window)
stazionamenti_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, stick=W)
#conversion stazionamenti


def helper():
    global stazionamenti_num
    global stazionamenti_entry
    if stazionamenti_entry.get():
        stazionamenti_num = int(stazionamenti_entry.get())
#avanti
def avanti():
    helper()
    print(stazionamenti_num)

avanti_btn=Button(window, text="Avanti", command=avanti).grid(columnspan=50, stick=E)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: so if i want to make a button and the command of the button executes the code to get stazionamenti_num  i can end this by using " return stazionamenti_num; " in my function related to the button?

Comment: the functions in the `command` should not `return` anything. You can copy your `stazionamenti_str.get()` in `avanti` along with the string checks i described. You will need to declare `global stazionamenti_num` in this function.

Comment: don't call the function in `command` i.e. remove the brackets. Declare the stazionamenti_num global within this function. This will mark the variable as a one available outside and will change it their. The num will be updated.

Comment: i posted an answer, just to let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
binari_1 = Radiobutton(window, text="1", command=lambda:binari(int(info.get())),variable=info,value=1).grid(column=1, row=0)

binari_2 = Radiobutton(window, text="2", command=lambda:binari(int(info.get())),variable=info,value=2).grid(column=2, row=0)
```

I think the [IntVar()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) seems to have a different approach or object being returned. Try converting it using `int()` function

Comment: sorry maybe i wasn't clear enough. i need to convert the stazionamenti entry box into an integer. For now i am using two variables for that: stazionamenti_str and stazionamenti_num. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended with this. But if i print(stazionamenti_num) it does not print it @abdullahQureshee

```
#stazionamenti
stazionamenti_label=Label(window, text="Stazionamenti: ").grid(column=0, row=1, stick=W)
stazionamenti_entry=Entry(window)
stazionamenti_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, stick=W)
#conversion stazionamenti
global stazionamenti_str
global stazionamenti_num
stazionamenti_str=""
def stazionamenti_convert():
    stazionamenti_num= int(stazionamenti_str)


#avanti
def avanti():
    if stazionamenti_str:
        stazionamenti_convert()
avanti_btn=Button(window, text="Avanti", command=avanti()).grid(columnspan=50, stick=E)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: write the global statements within convert function

Comment: It stills not working... Can you please send the complete code? It would be amazing

Comment: i;ve updated my answer. check it out. It has the code fragment